# Why isn't GitHub aware of the tags in my repository?

Tags: git, github

I had a local Git repository which I imported into my GitHub profile:

First, I created an empty repository on GitHub. Then, on my machine I did:

```
git remote add github <my-github-url>
git push -u github master
```

(I had only a master branch on the local repository)

My git version is **1.9.2** and my OS is Windows 7.

The problem is that I have about 20 - 30 tags on my local repository. They didn't make it to GitHub. I know this because:

- on the GitHub-repository page you can usually switch between branches and tags. There are no tags listed there for my project.
- if I clone the repository from GitHub somewhere else on my harddrive, everything is imported just fine except there are no tags in this copy (`git tag` returns nothing).

Why is this happening ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you try `git push --tags`?

Comment: @Peque No. I will try it as soon as I get home (I am at work now). But when you push a branch, shouldn't the tags be automatically pushed as well ? I mean, they're quite important in most cases...

Comment: @RaduMurzea: they are important, but that does not justify pushing them automatically. If you want a tag pushed, you must tell Git to push it (same goes for a branch. Git won't magically push any new branches you have)

Comment: @knittl totally agree about the branches, don't agree about the tags. This is kind of a "Git wtf" moment for me...

Comment: @Radu Murzea: I do not know if they should or they should not be pushed automatically. And I do not make the rules. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making my comment an answer, you should try:

```
git push --tags
```

Junio C Hamano (current maintainer of the Git project), [explains why tags should not be pushed automatically](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/rfd-auto-following-tags-upon-quot-git-push-quot-td6450398.html).